# Why do I get e8 00 00 00 00 for all libc function calls?

Tags: x86-64

I just started learning reverse engineering. The near call instruction (e8) is very confusing to me. It took me a while to figure out how address calculation works for local functions.

Now I'm looking at the output of

```
// gcc -c test.c 
void test() {
     puts("Hello from puts");
     printf("Hello from printf");
}
```

And it's `e8 00 00 00 00` for both calls. Somehow my disassembler can figure out which call's which.

Here's objdump output:

```
    0000000000000000 <_test>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
   8:   48 8d 3d 1f 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x1f]        # 2e <_test+0x2e>
   f:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   14 <_test+0x14>
  14:   48 8d 3d 23 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x23]        # 3e <_test+0x3e>
  1b:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
  1e:   b0 00                   mov    al,0x0
  20:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   25 <_test+0x25>
  25:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  28:   48 83 c4 10             add    rsp,0x10
  2c:   5d                      pop    rbp
  2d:   c3                      ret
```

Hopper's output:

```
_test:
0000000000000000   push  rbp
0000000000000001   mov   rbp, rsp
0000000000000004   sub   rsp, 0x10
0000000000000008   lea   rdi, qword [0x2e]      ; argument "s" for _puts
000000000000000f   call  _puts
0000000000000014   lea   rdi, qword [0x3e]      ; argument "format" for _printf
000000000000001b   mov   dword [rbp+var_4], eax
000000000000001e   mov   al, 0x0
0000000000000020   call  _printf
0000000000000025   mov   dword [rbp+var_8], eax
0000000000000028   add   rsp, 0x10
000000000000002c   pop   rbp
000000000000002d   ret                          ; endp
```

**Edit**

I found the answer to my initial question:

> If you're disassembling .o object files that haven't been linked yet,
>   the call address will just be a placeholder to be filled in by the
>   linker.

So how does the linker know which function is getting called?

Comment: @Alex : As a new contributor do not forget to mark the best answer as the right answer. It helps a lot the website statistics among the Stack-Exchange websites.

Comment: @perror I haven't got an answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `-dr` instead of plain `-d`, `objdump` will list *relocation info* next to the instructions. E.g. here's a random sample I just compiled

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
   9:   c7 44 24 18 a9 03 00    movl   $0x3a9,0x18(%esp)
  10:   00
  11:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
  18:   00
                        15: R_386_32    m1
  19:   c7 04 24 30 00 00 00    movl   $0x30,(%esp)
                        1c: R_386_32    .rodata
  20:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   21 <main+0x21>
                        21: R_386_PC32  wprintf
  25:   89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
  29:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  2e:   c9                      leave
  2f:   c3                      ret
```

You can see that call at 20 has a relocation info to `wprintf` (at 21, right at the bytes that correspond to the offset to the destination of the call). linker (`ld`) uses this information at link time to patch the instructions with the final resolved address of the function.

It seems Hopper used relocation info symbol's name for more user-friendly disassembly.

Comment: Thanks. You don't have `e8 00 00 00 00`. Did you build without `gcc -c` ? I want to understand how calls work without relocation info.